# Decision tree classifier prediction changes from one run of the model to the next

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-trees, prediction

I'm running a very basic gender `['male', 'female']` classifier using the sklearn `DecisionTreeClassifier` based on `[height, weight, shoe size]` in a Jupyter notebook.

The prediction changes from `male` to `female` for the same input as I keep running the model.

I don't understand how that's possible. Shouldn't the build of the model be completely deterministic and therefore output the same prediction each time for a specific input?

Here's my code:

```
X = [[190, 90, 43], [165, 65, 38], [170, 70, 39], [160, 56, 36], [190, 88, 45], 
[164, 63, 37]]
Y = ['male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female']

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X, Y)

print(clf.predict([[200, 70, 37]]))
```

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21394528/6020255

Comment: @oW_, thank you that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is a duplicate and the suggested link answers your question, for learning purposes I would like to suggest that you plot your DecisionTree every time you have a new run to see by yourself what happens behind the scenes:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  

from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus
dot_data = StringIO()

X = [[190, 90, 43], [165, 65, 38], [170, 70, 39], [160, 56, 36], [190, 88, 45], [164, 63, 37]]
Y = ['male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female']

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X, Y)

export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data,  
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True)

graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Once you may get:

[image]

where splitting is done on X0 feature, where as next run you may get:

[image]

where splitting is done on X1 feature.

If you wanna reproduce your result at every run, you can use `random_state = a_random_number` and then you should expect to get the same result every time as the same tree has been constructed every time!

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for taking the time to write this up.

Comment: Pleasure. Glad you find it helpful.